# How to create quiz from google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I have a sheet with questions and I'd like to write a script that will create a new form with these questions. I know how to create a form from Google script, but I do not understand how to:

1. Create a new form from questions sheet
2. Set the correct answer for the question (item in form)
3. Set points for the correct answer

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: We need more info to help here. Post your current work and a small set of data so we can understand. I found this link that may help you https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms now allow you to [create & grade quizzes](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=en) & you can get them up and running programatically too using Google Apps Script FormApp's [QuizFeedbackBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback-builder).

Hope this helps!